# ActionScript 3.0 - [Error] expecting identifier before 10128

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So I've been working on a flash game with a friend of mine and we encountered a error that we have been stuck on since yesterday.

The Errors:

```
 Line 5 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before 10128
 Line 5 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before 10129
 Line 5 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before 10200
```

Here is the code for the 3 files

**10128.as**

```
package 
{ 
    import flash.display.*;

    public dynamic class 10128 extends MovieClip //Line 5
    {
        public var back:Object;
    }
}
```

**10129.as**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public dynamic class 10129 extends MovieClip //Line 5
    {
        public var back:MovieClip;
    }
}
```

**10200.as**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public dynamic class 10200 extends MovieClip //Line 5
    {

    }
}
```

I've looked everywhere and I did view the other posts on this site regarding the same issue but It still didn't work. If anybody knows what's wrong I would appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class name **should** start with uppercase character. (updated "must" to "should")
Class name starting with lowercase character might also works, but **starting with numeric character doesn't work**.

See this link
http://wiki.opensemanticframework.org/index.php/AS3_Coding_Standards

Currently, your class name start with numeric character.
Change your file name and class name, for example...

**Test10128.as**

```
package 
{ 
    import flash.display.*;

    public dynamic class Test10128 extends MovieClip //Line 5
    {
        public var back:Object;
    }
}
```

**Test10129.as**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public dynamic class Test10129 extends MovieClip //Line 5
    {
        public var back:MovieClip;
    }
}
```

**Test10200.as**

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;

    public dynamic class Test10200 extends MovieClip //Line 5
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean the class name must be uppercase Character?

Comment: Currently, your class name start with numeric character.
Change your file name and class name.

Comment: Did you change both file name and class name?

Comment: Yup I changed all three of them

Comment: Your comment "I got more errors", but I think the errors coming from other classes (chat.as, xBut.as). Isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117149/discussion-between-yasuyuki-uno-and-ryan-fuhrman).

Comment: @RyanFuhrman, this answer is correct for your problem (click **correct tick** to mark it as solved). You always had those _new_ errrors, just Flash wasn't going to talk about them until you fixed this other main one (that you posted about). And when you fix those, the compiler might discover yet more issues with other code later. It's a sign the compiler is going forwards through your code...